# missing files in flask installation

Tags: python, heroku, installation, flask, gunicorn

I've been trying for a long while to install Flask.

Each time I run into the same error where I get the following warnings of no previously-included files. I'm not sure how to bypass this, because it's seemingly interfering with whatever it is I need or want to do down the line.

### I followed a basic [heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python) successfully up until I had to push the git, where it failed. Any help is really appreciated.

```
(venv)Shahs-MacBook-Pro:helloflask ssaullah$ pip install Flask gunicorn

Downloading/unpacking Flask
  Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB): 544kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Flask

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
Downloading/unpacking gunicorn
  Downloading gunicorn-0.17.4.tar.gz (372kB): 372kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gunicorn

Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug>=0.7 (from Flask)
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.9.1.tar.gz (1.1MB): 1.1MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Werkzeug

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'werkzeug/debug/templates'
    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Downloading/unpacking Jinja2>=2.4 (from Flask)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.7.tar.gz (377kB): 377kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Jinja2

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'custom_fixers'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
Downloading/unpacking itsdangerous>=0.21 (from Flask)
  Downloading itsdangerous-0.21.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package itsdangerous

Downloading/unpacking markupsafe (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask)
  Downloading MarkupSafe-0.18.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package markupsafe

Installing collected packages: Flask, gunicorn, Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous, markupsafe
  Running setup.py install for Flask

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
  Running setup.py install for gunicorn

    Installing gunicorn_paster script to /Users/ssaullah/Desktop/tryweb/helloflask/venv/bin
    Installing gunicorn script to /Users/ssaullah/Desktop/tryweb/helloflask/venv/bin
    Installing gunicorn_django script to /Users/ssaullah/Desktop/tryweb/helloflask/venv/bin
  Running setup.py install for Werkzeug

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'werkzeug/debug/templates'
    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  Running setup.py install for Jinja2

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'custom_fixers'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
  Running setup.py install for itsdangerous

  Running setup.py install for markupsafe

    building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c markupsafe/_speedups.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.o
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -g build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.so
Successfully installed Flask gunicorn Werkzeug Jinja2 itsdangerous markupsafe
Cleaning up...
```

### EDIT:

### I should've included this: the error that comes up when I try and push git at the end of the tutorial.

```
Shahs-MacBook-Pro:helloflask ssaullah$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 731 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.36)
-----> Installing Pip (1.3.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

       Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Flask

           warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
       Downloading/unpacking Jinja2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Jinja2

       Downloading/unpacking Polygon==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Polygon==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: 3.0.5, 3.0.4a-src, 2.0.5, 2.0.4.macosx-10.6-universal, 2.0.4)
       No distributions matching the version for Polygon==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:immense-waters-4799.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:immense-waters-4799.git'
```

Comment: I think the error has to do with the Polygon==2.0.1 requirement not being satisfied.

Comment: thank you; do you have any suggestions on how to satisfy the requirement?

Comment: hi, read my answer below and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

This (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Polygon/) is the link to the Polygon on PyPi. You can append the version number after that to retrieve the url for the appropriate version of Polygon (eg. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Polygon/3.0.5). Using 2.0.1 gives me a not found page (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Polygon/2.0.1). You might want to find an appropriate version, such as 2.0.3 , 2.0.4 , or 2.0.5 .

Links page on PyPi:
https://pypi.python.org/simple/Polygon/

The github repository for Polygon2: https://github.com/jraedler/Polygon2

Hope that helps.